# Do you need to change the language of variables to English when asking a question?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, code, languages

For instance, I am Dutch and most of the time is I use Dutch words to declare variables. for smaller lines of code it's easy to translate, but is it something you should always do?

Is the question less understandable if I use a different language for variables and literals?

for example:

```
percentagewolk = (randint(0, 100))
percentagezon = (randint(0, 100))

if percentagezon > percentagewolk:
  print('de dag is zonnig')
else:
  print('de dag was bewolkt')
```

would be

```
percentagecloudy = (randint(0, 100))
percentagesunny = (randint(0, 100))

if percentagesunny > percentagecloudy:
  print('the day is sunny')
else:
  print('the day is cloudy')
```

Comment: I would prefer an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that uses English variable and method names, yes. If only to prevent that viewers of your question get the impression you simply did a copy/paste dump of your code and expected us to fix it for you. With non-English content in the code that becomes much more obvious.

Comment: English is to coding what french is to the cousine ;) btw - you already use English in `percentagewolk`, dutch-english hybrids might be harder to read than plain English ..

Comment: As a Dutch person myself, I have to say I prefer English variables over the Dutch ones in questions. Especially in an English context.

Comment: Also @iLuvLogix percentage is actually a dutch word as well. While it can be read as a dutch-english hybrid, it is an unintended one ;)

Comment: @Codeer : Thx for clueing me up - i thought it's called `procent` in dutch..

Comment: @iLuvLogix percentage/percentage, procent/percent.

Comment: on-topic: I frequently see code where variables and method names are Spanish. It does not hinder my understanding of the code; I don't need to maintain it, just spot a mistake in it most of the time. But the name of the game is increasing the chance of getting an answer, in that respect I would post fully English code yeah. Maybe if you have to translate often enough you finally convince yourself to stop making your life harder and just write fully English code ;)

Comment: It's a fine line. Theoretically you could use one-letter variables and the question should be the same. Function names, however, should be as clear as possible, and I consider literal text output in an unknown language virtually worthless. ("Why does this ouput 'Sóbrćyńy" instead of "Dänø"?")

Comment: Dutch is not too bad, just looks like English with a lot of new swear words added to the vocabulary.  It certainly needs some, the f-word is rather meager.  Now Polish, that's a language whose snippets make everybody swear.  There used to be a lot more of them at SO, I wonder what they are doing today.  I'd guess they all learned that it is hard to get help that way.  Which is what matters most, keep it readable and you'll have much better odds to get some.

Comment: @Stijn I didn't find that thread when I was searching for a similar question before posting this, should i close this now? Since other people might still be interested in posting here.

Comment: That's up to you, if you think the proposed duplicate adequately answers your question then I suggest you cast the final close vote. If not, it's up to other users to agree or disagree with the proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 15):

You don't necessarily *need* to, but I'd highly encourage it. The ideal question should be about a generic concept or API usage anyway, so ideally your code sample would be the *minimum necessary code to illustrate the problem* written specifically for the question and not for us to do a bug hunt in your actual code. Even if not, it's easier for English speakers to follow your code logic if it has comprehensible variable names; instead of what are, for all intents and purposes, meaningless symbols.

If, of course, the question is about a specific bug in your specific code, changing variable names *may* resolve or obscure the actual bug; so if you're going to change anything about the code, make sure the same issue is still reproducible with the changed code.

Answer (score 8):

**Need** might be a strong word. The basic rule of thumb for Stack Overflow is that you should make your code snippet as straight forward and easy to understand as possible.

Can this snippet be understood by someone who doesn't speak Dutch? Probably.
Would it be easier to understand if the names and string printed out were in English? Probably, too.

So while **need** is a strong word, and I wouldn't say I'd automatically vote to close a question with non-English variable names (heck, I even answered a few of those!), I'd definitely encourage you to make the extra effort to translate your code. If you expect others to freely donate their time to help you solve a problem you're struggling with, wouldn't it be courteous to devote a couple of minutes of your time to make sure you're presenting the question is the easiest form to understand?

Answer (score 3):

You do not **need** to change them.

Any minimally competent coder shouldn't have a problem in following the logic in either code-snippet, even without understanding the variable names and literals in your code.

That being said, having any part of your post in a different language will make your post **slightly harder to understand** and could give a feeling of *"I've just copied pasted my project here for you to fix, pls"*.

It's always better to build a stand-alone MCVE anyway, so when doing that you can use new variables names and literals.

When building the MCVE you'll also eliminate many trivial errors that could be present in your original code, and may help you fix the problem before posting the question.

In that sense, feeling obliged to translate your variable names and literals may also help you solve your problem directly, which is a huge bonus.